# The word "does" refer in a sentence

Tags: pronouns

> The moon itself rotates, but it **does** so very slowly.

In this sentence, what is the word "does"  referring to, "rotates" or "itself rotates"?

Comment: "Does so" refers to the verb *rotates*. You can even replace "does so" with "rotates" in the second sentence without changing its (the second sentence's) meaning.

Comment: Are there differences between the word "does" and "does so" for making a question of "reference"?

Comment: Yes, you wouldn't say "but it does very slowly", because the "does" requires something else following it that links back to the action. Consider the alternative form "but it does this very slowly". Does this, does that etc. The important thing is to use a word that refers to the action, but isn't specifically the action. Saying "but it does rotate very slowly" or "but it does turn very slowly" are not natural

Answer (score 4):

The moon itself rotates, but it **does so** very slowly.

The moon itself rotates, but it **performs this action** very slowly.

> She dances, but she does so only if she likes the music.

We can also use the pronoun **it** to refer back to that which is done:

> He listens to talk radio, but he does it only in his car.